# double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000001a880a0 *** on combinatory algorithm using vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, memory-management, combinations

I'm programming an algorithm to calculate the Steiner Tree on a given graph by calculating the minimum tree of each combination of vertices, but my combinatory algorithm doesnt seem to manage the memory use right, but I can't see where I'm failing to do it...

It works as follows, the algorithm receives a vector with the vertices that must be included always in the graph, so the first thing is to create a vector with the optional vertices, the one that we will combine (I used 10 for testing porpouse), then it calculates the combinations from 1 element to k elements (k being less than the total size of the optional vertices set).

We will generate the combinations of indexes (insted of directly elements, as it's easier this way) and then include the elements in those indexes in the vComb vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//Function that calculates the next combination
bool next_comb(vector<int>& indComb, const int k, const int n) {
    int i = k - 1;
    indComb[i]++;
    while((i >= 0) && (indComb[i] >= n-k+1+i)){
        i--;
        indComb[i]++;
    }
    if (indComb[0] > n - k) //We've arrived to the combination (n-k, n-k+1, ..., n)
        return false; //We can't generate more combinations
    //Combination is in form(..., x, n, n, n, ..., n).
    //We will put it in form (..., x, x + 1, x + 2, ...)
    for (i = i + 1; i < k; ++i)
        indComb[i] = indComb[i - 1] + 1;
    return true;
}

//Checks if element is in vector
bool is_in(const int n,const vector<int> v){
  for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    if(n==v[i]) return true;
  return false;
}

void ST(const vector<int> vMandatory){
  cout << "V Mandatory: ";
  for(int i=0;i<vMandatory.size();i++)
    cout << vMandatory[i] << " ";
  cout << " " << endl;

  //Create and initializate the vector that contains the optional vertices
  vector<int> vOptional(10-vMandatory.size());
  int j=0;
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    if(!is_in(i,vMandatory)){
      vOptional[j] = i;
      j++;
    }
  }

  cout << "V Optional: ";
  for(int i=0;i<vOptional.size();i++)
    cout << vOptional[i] << " ";
  cout << " " << endl;


  int k = 1; //Initialize number of elements to combine
  int n = vOptional.size(); //Number of elements inside de set to combine
  vector<int> indComb;  //Vector that will keep the combined indexes of the combination
  vector<int> vComb;  //Vector that will keep the combined elements
  //We control that the number of elements in the combination can't exceed the number of elements in the set
  while(k <= vOptional.size()){
    indComb.resize(k);
    vComb.resize(k);

    //Preparare the first combination
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
      indComb[i] = i;
      vComb[i] = vOptional[indComb[i]];
    }

    cout << "V Primera Combinación: ";
    for(int i=0;i<vComb.size();i++)
      cout << vComb[i] << " ";
    cout << " " << endl;

    //We make the rest of combinations
    while(next_comb(indComb,k,n)){
      for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
        vComb[i] = vOptional[indComb[i]];

      cout << "V Next Combinations: ";
      for(int i=0;i<vComb.size();i++)
        cout << vComb[i] << " ";
      cout << " " << endl;
    }
    k++;
    cout << k << endl;
  }
}

int main(){
  vector<int> vObligatorios(3);
  vObligatorios[0] = 0;
  vObligatorios[1] = 1;
  vObligatorios[2] = 2;
  ST(vObligatorios);
}
```

This is the error that compiler gives me

```
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000001a880a0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f8f9a4c67e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7fe0a)[0x7f8f9a4cee0a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f8f9a4d298c]
./a.out[0x402612]
./a.out[0x4022c4]
./a.out[0x401c98]
./a.out[0x40213e]
./a.out[0x401b78]
./a.out[0x401823]
./a.out[0x4010b4]
./a.out[0x40149c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f8f9a46f830]
./a.out[0x400bb9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00404000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 14156577                           /home/pedro/Desktop/a.out
00603000-00604000 r--p 00003000 08:06 14156577                           /home/pedro/Desktop/a.out
00604000-00605000 rw-p 00004000 08:06 14156577                           /home/pedro/Desktop/a.out
01a76000-01aa8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f8f94000000-7f8f94021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8f94021000-7f8f98000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8f9a146000-7f8f9a24e000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2621535                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f8f9a24e000-7f8f9a44d000 ---p 00108000 08:06 2621535                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f8f9a44d000-7f8f9a44e000 r--p 00107000 08:06 2621535                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f8f9a44e000-7f8f9a44f000 rw-p 00108000 08:06 2621535                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f8f9a44f000-7f8f9a60e000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2621530                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f8f9a60e000-7f8f9a80e000 ---p 001bf000 08:06 2621530                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f8f9a80e000-7f8f9a812000 r--p 001bf000 08:06 2621530                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f8f9a812000-7f8f9a814000 rw-p 001c3000 08:06 2621530                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f8f9a814000-7f8f9a818000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8f9a818000-7f8f9a82e000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2625962                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8f9a82e000-7f8f9aa2d000 ---p 00016000 08:06 2625962                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8f9aa2d000-7f8f9aa2e000 rw-p 00015000 08:06 2625962                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8f9aa2e000-7f8f9aba0000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 5244862                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f8f9aba0000-7f8f9ada0000 ---p 00172000 08:06 5244862                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f8f9ada0000-7f8f9adaa000 r--p 00172000 08:06 5244862                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f8f9adaa000-7f8f9adac000 rw-p 0017c000 08:06 5244862                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f8f9adac000-7f8f9adb0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8f9adb0000-7f8f9add6000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2621445                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f8f9afb4000-7f8f9afb9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8f9afd2000-7f8f9afd5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8f9afd5000-7f8f9afd6000 r--p 00025000 08:06 2621445                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f8f9afd6000-7f8f9afd7000 rw-p 00026000 08:06 2621445                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f8f9afd7000-7f8f9afd8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffd45daf000-7ffd45dd0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffd45de6000-7ffd45de8000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffd45de8000-7ffd45dea000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info : `g++ -Wall -g`. Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), your `gdb` debugger, and *think* on your bugs.

Comment: *but I can't see where I'm failing to do it..* -- You could replace your usage of `[ ]` to access your vector elements with `at()` so that you get an `out_of_range` exception error instead of just a seg fault.  If you did that, and then incrementally put back `[ ]`, to see which `at()` call is causing the exception, you would see that `i--; indComb.at(i)++;` is throwing the `std::out_of_range` exception, just as the answer given shows you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
while((i >= 0) && (indComb[i] >= n-k+1+i)){
    i--;
    indComb[i]++;
}
```

you may make `i` negative, causing the next line to be undefined.
Adding some tracing for that case verifies that it does happen.

(You're likely overwriting the memory manager's internal data for the vector's allocated storage.)